# How do I expose a shell on a remote Windows Server 2003 box that Windows XP box can access?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, remote-access

Ideally I would like the following requirements met:

1. Free solution.
2. Multiple users can log in at once.
3. It's shell only (no Remote Desktop!)

Any ideas?

I have full admin rights on the box.

As near as I can tell, we did not pay for telnet services, either, so that's not an option, not that I'd know how to set that up either. That'd be an acceptable answer if nothing else presents itself and it's well documented.

Comment: Are you allowed to install an sshd on the box?

Comment: should be able to. But it needs to be talking to CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet on Windows Server does not require additional licensing.  Its free to use and easy to [set up](http://www.ehow.com/how_5218290_install-telnet-server.html).

Comment: It's also not exactly secure to make available over the internet, unless you can wrap it in a secure tunnel (ssl, vpn, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to use [Windows Remote Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) built into Windows operating systems. That's Free, Multiple users can log in at once and it's shell only.

you'll find a lot of resources when you follow the link to assist you setting it up.